# Fetch all the task links of a Project with Start - Id and End - Id of every task link

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, project-online

**My requirement is to fetch all the task links of a Project with Start - Id and End - Id of every task link.**

Currently I'm only able to fetch LinkId, ProjUid, Lag and Dependency type using REST API -

**https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/Projects('ProjectGUID')/TaskLinks**

Then to Get **Start - Id** and **End - Id**, I have to again send two additional API requests and takes a lot of time when I have to fetch a total of **8000+ Task Links** in a project with **8500 tasks**.